# Elastic search curl query not working

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, rethinkdb

Im trying to run the following search query in Elastic Search using a Curl:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/db/table_one/_search?q=Summary:None'
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]","status":503}
```

Im unable to debug this.Is there a specific issue with the way Im writing the curl command?Thanks!(My databases name is db and the table Im searching on is table_one-Im using RethinkDB)

Comment: check the index status `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/db/_status?pretty=1`

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch first checks shard availability. Your error looks like there are no functioning shards in your Rethink DB instance. Can you confirm the health of the shards?